# Overlapping R subplots

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

I am trying to make a plot that has all the following plots shown in rows

```
fin_def<-subplot(fit_def, over_def,mov_def,pass_def,d_def) %>% layout(title = list(text = "Def Stats"))
fin_mid<-subplot(fit_mid, over_mid,mov_mid,pass_mid,d_mid)%>% layout(title = list(text = "Mid Stats"))
fin_fwd<-subplot(fit_fwd, over_fwd,mov_fwd,pass_fwd,d_fwd)%>% layout(title = list(text = "Fwd Stats"))
subplot(t_comp,fin_def,fin_mid,fin_fwd, nrows = 4, margin = 10)
```

but its overlapping the plots instead of showing them in different rows
[overlapped plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZmpS.png)

the t_comp is a flowchart that i make in ggplot2 and converted it into a plotly plot using ggplotly() function other are 3 plots are combined radar plots made using plotly.

```
plots <- list(t_comp, fin_def, fin_mid, fin_fwd)
plots <- lapply(plots, subplot)
subplot(plots, nrows = 4, margin = 100)
```

already tried increasing the margins and make a subplot using lapply
didn't work at all